# Find the contents of a directory

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get the contents of a directory with javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Not really* because of security reasons. You are trying to access client's file system !!

**Note:** There is **[FSO (File System Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50%28VS.85%29.aspx)** but to my knowledge it only works in IE.

**Useful Resources:**

http://www.c-point.com/JavaScript/articles/file_access_with_JavaScript.htm
http://4umi.com/web/javascript/fileread.php

Comment: There are new ways to access the clients file system with the new spec. They're just rarely used.

Comment: IIRC - can't use the FSO from inside a web page to scan the local drives.

Answer (score 1):

No, not with JavaScript that runs within a browser sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean JavaScript running inside a web browser, then no.

If you are running from somewhere else, (e.g. cscript.exe from a Windows command line, or ASP server side) then yes.

Which scenario are you referring to?